# Azure WebApplication can't able to access storage account

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

For security reasons, I enabled the selected networks option for my storage account but my web app can't able to access that storage account and I enabled "Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account" option but still my web app cant able to access storage account.

Comment: How do you access the storage account?

Comment: we have deployed our code to web app in that code we configured Storage account name and key for accessing storage account

Comment: So you don't use a shared access signature?

Comment: No, we didn't used that

Comment: Take a moment to read the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage